# Unable to install HP OfficeJet V40 network printer with Windows 10

Tags: printer

I'm unable to install HP OfficeJet V40 printer residing behind JetDirect 175 print server on a laptop with Windows 10: it's not among those listed in printer make/model selection view no matter how many times I click Windows Update. Is there a way to extract its driver files from another laptop with Windows 7? It showed up there among those listed as soon as I clicked Windows Update on that laptop, and so was successfully installed.

Thanks & Regards!

Answer (score 0):

Sorted: the following pack had several drivers including the V40 one, which Windows 10 was happy with.
https://drp.su/en/devices/printer/hp/hp-officejet-v40?os=windows-10-x64